# Android Toast without image

Tags: java, android, image, hide, toast

I want to know how can I remove and change the App icon displayed when I show a Toast in Android application using Java.
Thanks in advance.

class Toast doesn't have any method to modify it. i don't know if setView helps to do that or not but it is deprecated. Tried the snackBar but it looks totally different.

Comment: AFAIK, what you want is not possible on modern versions of Android.

Comment: you cant change the app icon after the app is installed.
you can use the snackbar for that, but you should change the view of that.